# Can I have only foreign key in a database instead of a primary key?

Tags: database

I was thinking, can I not have primary key in a column?
For example, like this query:

```
create table EXAMPLE1(
id int identity(1,1),
username varchar(20),
password varchar(20)
CONSTRAINT fk_id FOREIGN KEY(id)
REFERENCES EXAMPLE0(id)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unique index, you can use it's fields in a foreign key. It doesn't have to be a primary key.
Edit: this structure might be a solution:

```
create table employee(
    id int identity primary key not null, name varchar(50)
)
create table account(
    employeeId int, accountId int
    CONSTRAINT fk_employeeId FOREIGN KEY(employeeId) REFERENCES employee(id)
)
```

This way you should manage accountId field manually. As the customer adds new accounts you should increment accountId accordingly.

Comment: I am trying to create employee table and account table and I was wondering if i can just use the employee id as foreign to table account to define who is the account user. :)

Comment: OK, according to what I figure out from what you've described, such a structure might solve your problem: sorry, table structure did not fit in here. I'll add that as an answer.